# Image and Video Files not showing up in Gallery

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung, default-applications

I am using Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean OS Smart Phone, All the images and video files present in `My Files`(default file browser app for android) are not showing up in `Gallery`(default app), and Other Apps(e.g., `MX Player`) are also not able to detect the media present in devices internal storage. Please help me to fix this issue, and Does this behavior, drain my phones battery ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I charged via computer USB all my photos were in the folder `\Phone\DCIM\Camera`.

All I did was move the photo files to a folder in the computer then copy them back to the camera folder and all of them could be seen again. Took about 2 minutes for 400 photos.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue as well.

I have no idea why this works, but if i copy the folders to my computer, delete the ones on my phone, then copy them back, they all appear

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no `.nomedia` file in the folder or in the parent folder (Sdcard). This prevents media files to be shown in the Gallery. Be aware that `.nomedia` is an hidden file, so you won't see it until you activate *shown hidden files* in your file browser.

Answer (score 0):

I spent one hour with T-Mobile tech level 2 (supervisor) on this same issue. I followed the advice above, enabled **`Show Hidden Files`** and, sure enough, all the way at the bottom was a `.nomedia` file. As soon as I deleted that, the photos and videos started showing up in the Gallery.